# CygWin cmd "source" and renaming with "mv"

Tags: cygwin

I am a bit curious about CygWin command `source` and renaming with `mv`.

When I run in source file cmd `mv` and would rename some file in my computer, it renames files well, but unhappily it puts at the end of name also the cryptic character.

f.e.: `1A6CSAB000A1_51D9.pdf`and in this case, my computer isn´t able to open the file. 
But when I run it without cmd `source` (and source file), just with

`mv A.phd.1 B.phd.1`

in CygWin, it works well and rename files without cryptic character.
Any idea how to deal with this issue?

Thanks in advance and sorry, if there is similar question, I didn´t find it.

Gabi

Comment: please describe your use of shell builtin `source`. It is not clear what  you are  doing and expecting

Comment: Check to see if the file you are sourcing has CR LF line endings. Use `cat -e FILE` to see line endings. Use `dos2unix FILE` or `d2u FILE` to fix the file. In the long term, find out how to make your favorite editor write unix line endings and preserve line endings.

Comment: I designed commands for `source file` in excel via cmd `concatenate` and I think, this was the problem. I am suprised that notepad, where I inserted data by Ctrl+C and Ctrl+V didn´t clear whole cryptic characters. Also I supposed that Notepad++ show these characters, if they are present, but it also didn´t show anything. 

But I solved the problem via `R` . I merged separated cells and exported into `.txt` file and now it works.

Thanks a lot for your recommendation.